# Shell script to append text to each file?

Tags: bash, concatenation

I have a folder full of text files.  I need to append the same block of text to each of them (and of course overwrite the original file).

I was wondering what the correct Bash shell syntax would be for this. Would I use cat?

I have done a few batch scripts but I'm not a Bash expert.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Overwrite or append, both are exclusive?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use append redirection.

```
for f in *.txt
do
  cat footer >> "$f"
done
```

Comment: The OP states "and of course overwrite the original files", so I suspect '>' is desired instead of '>>'

Comment: @wiliam, no, this answer appends the footer text to each file.  you don't want to wipe out each file's actual data.

Comment: Where `footer` is a file containing the block of text that must be appended to each file.

Comment: Yes, what Ignacio said. I want to append the new text file snippet to each of the original files and then save them once appended.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If you're needing to do this via a script, you can use echo and append redirection to get the extra text into the files.

```bsh
FILES=pathto/*
for f in $FILES ; do
    echo "#extra text" >> $f
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i.bak "$ a $(<file_block_of_text)" *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Variant of kurumi's answer:

```
sed -i.bak "\$aTEXTTOINSERT" *.txt
```

For more details, see [SED: insert something to the last line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20573/sed-insert-something-to-the-last-line)

Answer (score -1):

very simply one which worked well for me

```
#!/bin/sh
FILES="./files/*"

for f in $FILES
do
    echo '0000000' | cat - $f > temp && mv temp $f
done
```

Comment: in bash you have >> pipe operator, you should use it