# Append file contents to the bottom of existing file in Bash

Tags: bash, sed, awk, append

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shell script to append text to each file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586293/shell-script-to-append-text-to-each-file)
>   [How to append output to the end of text file in SHELL Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207573/how-to-append-output-to-the-end-of-text-file-in-shell-script)

I'm trying to work out the best way to insert api details into a pre-existing config. I thought about using `sed` to insert the contents of the api text file to the bottom of the config.inc file. I've started the script but it doesn't work and it wipes the file.

```
#!/bin/bash

CONFIG=/home/user/config.inc
API=/home/user/api.txt

sed -e "\$a $API" > $CONFIG
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 249, accepted):

This should work:

```
 cat "$API" >> "$CONFIG"
```

You need to use the `>>` operator to append to a file.  Redirecting with `>` causes the file to be overwritten. (truncated).

Comment: For single string, use `echo` like this `echo "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_112" >> ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Why `echo` instead of `cat`?

Comment: `cat` writes the contents of the named files to stdout.  `echo` writes the arguments to stdout.  They do different things.

Comment: Should use 'more' instead of 'cat' as cat will spawn a new process.

Comment: @PTHuynh `more` is a bad choice.  The purpose of `more` is to buffer output to a tty and break it up into sections for interactive human consumption.  There is nothing interactive about writing to a file.  If some shell has `more` as a builtin but not `cat` is an implementation detail.

Comment: `cat "$API"  "$CONFIG" > temp && mv temp "$CONFIG"` to prepend instead of append.