# How to append one file that includes '< >' to another in bash script

Tags: xml, linux, bash, shell, unix

Is there a way to append one file to another in a bash script without it complaining about the `<` `>` characters? I'm trying to append a file that contains some xml to another but it keeps throwing a

`syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'`

`'<myTag>'`

The operation is simply `myFile.txt >> otherFile.xml`

I know they're placeholder characters but I haven't been able to turn up any results on making them get interpreted as literals

Comment: @Nemo very true, I don't know why I thought `>>` would be an exception

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `cat`:

```
cat myfile.txt >>otherFile.xml
```

Otherwise, you're trying to run `myfile.txt` as an executable; the problem has nothing to do with the arrow-bracket characters embedded within the file's contents.

---

By the way -- XML documents can only legally contain a single root, and are not allowed to have content outside of that root, so your new file probably isn't valid XML.

Comment: Ya I realize that, I have some scripting for deleting the closing tag, appending xml and then readding it. It's a wonderful hack of a script but no one else has to see it but myself so I'm okay with it. If you have any good suggestions for dealing with xml in bash I'm open to suggsetions. This is a personal script so I don't have to worry about other users.

Comment: Should there be an extra space? Like `cat myfile.txt >> otherFile.xml` similar to the syntax at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13181820/3767980

Comment: @sreya, I'm a very big fan of XMLStarlet -- http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net -- as a toolkit for manipulating XML files from bash.

Comment: @PhysicalChemist, that's a question of style, and peoples' opinions differ. Personally, I consider the additional whitespace poor form.

Comment: @sreya, ...notably, XMLStarlet contains `pyx` and `p2x` commands, which convert XML to and from a very easy-to-parse line-oriented format.