# How to write end of file with new line in linux?

Tags: linux, syslog

I want to write, a script output into logfile at the end with new line..

with this command, it replace the file.

```
echo "hai" > /tmp/syslog.txt
```

but I need add "hai" with existing file content at the end with new line..

thanks in advance..

Comment: [How to append output to the end of a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6207573/608639), [Append file contents to the bottom of existing file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13181725/608639), etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append output to the end of a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207573/how-to-append-output-to-the-end-of-a-text-file)

Answer (score 3):

just simple like this:

```
echo "hai" >> /tmp/syslog.txt
```

:)

Answer (score -1):

Using option `\n` – New line with backspace interpreter `-e` treats new line from where it is used.

```
echo -e "\nHai" >> /tmp/syslog.txt
```